# Unique collection view in table view cell, like snapchat stories

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to include an optional (sometimes there sometimes not) unique view in the top most part of my tableview (meaning it will scroll with my tableview). This view will likely be complex having it's own collection view within it. Since the view will be complex I'm looking for some advice or perhaps other better ways to execute this, snapchat stories table has this functionality

[image]
[image]

The options I'm seeing:

1. Make the view the topmost cell
2. Have this view be the header (dosn't seem like it'd scale like for example what if I wanted 2 view or have them somewhere in the middle of the table)
3. Maybe put the tableview in a scroll view with this unique view being defined in the scroll view?

What I don't like about these options is:

1. Because this view is optional I'll need to mess with the indexpath to DataSrouce logic to complensate for this new cell
2. Because I'm treating this view as a cell I'll have to include some ugly logic like if indexpath is 1 then cell is this unique view

Is there a better way to include such an element? I like the idea of keeping them seperate which would have been easy if this element did not have to scroll with the table cell

Snapchat stories page actually has many different sections with unique cells in each, are they really just using a tableview and feeding it different types of cells depending on the index? Seems like it would get messy and unmaintainable in the long run

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with too much on one view. There is a way to have a UIView pop on another view controller and whatever is in that view as well. I would say from what you want is one UIViewController using either a UIView as the optional Unique cell at the top with a collection view below it. When you would scroll the collection view you could have the view slide up. Or if you want the snapchat stories like option it looks to me to be 2 collection views one going horizontal the other going vertical and based on which one it pulls different information or displays a different custom cell. Another option is to possibly have a CollectionView with only 2 static cells and it scrolls vertically. The top static cell will be your header and your bottom static cell will contain your other tableView, yes messy but doable.

Good luck and have fun!